# Access sharepoint online list from mobile app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am facing a problem where I need to show the data of sharepoint online list in a mobile app. mobile app can access the data via rest api. but how can i find the sharepoint context as app is external and sits outside boundary of sharepoint.

Any link to the solution or sample code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you check the SharePoint mobile app(not sure I understand you clearly) https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/mobile-app

Comment: As I have already written it is a public app not a sharepoint app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write REST API which will access SharePoint list data using managed Client object model(CSOM) and return data as JSON. 
Following are the detailed steps:
1. Create REST API to access SharePoint list using CSOM
2. Call API from mobile app and include username and password in header in encrypted format
3. Inside API, Decrypt header and use that Username and Password to access SharePoint list.

Sample code for API:

[image]

[image]